# ckan custom harvester '__junk' validation

Tags: ckan

I succesfully implemented a custom Harvester in my localhost CKAN installation (1.8), but when I move on another (should be the same configuration) machine, I got this error:

```
2013-02-13 11:18:21,670 DEBUG [ckanext.patstatweb.harvesters] In PatStatWebHarvester fetch_stage
2013-02-13 11:18:21,981 DEBUG [ckanext.patstatweb.harvesters] In PatStatWebHarvester import_stage
2013-02-13 11:18:22,357 INFO  [ckanext.harvest.harvesters.base] Package with GUID 9d15e19d1b17ac432dd704542a384304f7a37992 does not exist, let's create it
2013-02-13 11:18:22,384 ERROR [ckanext.harvest.harvesters.base] {'  junk': 'The input field __junk was not expected.'}
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ckan/pyenv/src/ckanext-harvest/ckanext/harvest/harvesters/base.py", line 165, in _create_or_update_package
    new_package = get_action('package_create_rest')(context, package_dict)
  File "/home/ckan/pyenv/src/ckan/ckan/logic/action/create.py", line 723, in     package_create_rest
    dictized_after = _get_action('package_create')(context, dictized_package)
  File "/home/ckan/pyenv/src/ckan/ckan/logic/action/create.py", line 137, in package_create
    raise ValidationError(errors)
ValidationError: {'  junk': 'The input field __junk was not expected.'}
2013-02-13 11:18:22,392 ERROR [ckanext.harvest.harvesters.base] Invalid package with GUID 9d15e19d1b17ac432dd704542a384304f7a37992: {'__junk': ['The input field __junk was not expected.']}
```

Any insights on this?

Answer (score 2):

The problem was caused by a bug with the organization setup of CKAN and the harvester plugin

This solves the issue https://github.com/okfn/ckan/pull/391

Comment: @mammadori, are you able to test this patch and confirm (or not) that it works?